# react native how to show 2 decimals after sum in text

Tags: react-native

I am showing value in the text widget and sum it like this

```
<Text style={{
  fontSize: 14,
  fontWeight: "bold",
  color: "black"
}}>
  {route.params.order.OrderCheckouts.AmountPaid.toFixed(2) + route.params.order.OrderCheckouts.ServiceCharges.toFixed(2)} SAR
</Text>
```

The issue is its show value like this `80.000.00`

How I can show it like `80.00` mean total 2 decimals after sum

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const num =
  route.params.order.OrderCheckouts.AmountPaid +
  route.params.order.OrderCheckouts.ServiceCharges;

<Text
  style={{
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "black",
  }}
>
  {`${num.toFixed(2)}`}
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are adding two strings which are actually getting appended.
This is the reason why you are getting `80.000.00`. So, in case your 2 values are `80.0` and `40.0`, you ll get the sum as `80.40.0` which is going to be the result of string concatination.
Convert them to `number` type and then add them. This will be helpful.

```
const num =
  +route.params.order.OrderCheckouts.AmountPaid +
  +route.params.order.OrderCheckouts.ServiceCharges;

<Text
  style={{
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "black",
  }}
>
  {`${num.toFixed(2)}`}
</Text>
```

This will make sure that both of the values are converted to numbers and then added.